# Database in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a script, which is reading a google sheet and returning 
its content.I want to store all data to database.

```
var request = gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.get(params);
request.then(function(response) {
    console.log(response.result.values[2][2]);
}, function(reason) {
    console.error('error: ' + reason.result.error.message);
});
}
```

how to store it to mysql database or how to make recognize this return data to 
    PHP script

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do a PHP page to receive your data. To send your data, you should use an AJAX requests that will send your data to the php script. Let's have a look on XML HTTP Request with Javascript on Google, or you can read this : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX